# Access and store value by index in a pointer

Tags: c

I've got an assignment where I have to sum whole numbers up to 100 digits.

They gave me this struct to represent big numbers (I think there are better ways to represent this, but I'm not allowed to modify it):

```
typedef struct {
  char* string;
  int lengthError;
} BigNumber;
```

Where `string` is the number itself and `lengthError` is the length of the number or an error that is a previously defined enum.

I've also have the implementation of the sum function

```
BigNumber *sum(BigNumber* num1, BigNumber* num2) {
    BigNumber* result = malloc(sizeof(BigNumber));
    int limit = getLength(num1->lengthError, num2->lengthError);
    result->string = malloc(limit);
    int digitResult;
    int index = limit -1;
    int carry = 0;

    while(index != -1) {
        int d1 = ((int)num1->string[index]) - ((int)'0');
        int d2 = ((int)num2->string[index]) - ((int)'0');
        digitResult = d1 + d2 + carry;

        if (digitResult > 9) {
            digitResult = digitResult - 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }

        itoa(digitResult, &result->string[index], 10); //I think this is the problem
        index--;
    }

    result->string[limit] = '\0';
    printf("result: %s\n", result->string);
    return result;
}
```

I haven't finished writing that function, I know there are a lot of flaws in it, but the problem is that I can't get to sum 12 + 12. The result I get is 2.

I thought approaching this problem by picking the lasts character of both numbers, transform them into an `int` and sum them having in mind the carry digit. After I got the result in `digitResult` I try to convert it to a char and store it in the corresponding position of the `result->string` pointer

Once it has finished the operation, I add an `\0` at the last position of the `result->string`.

So the question is, how do I make this operation to work as desired? Debugging the code, I noticed that the first time it stores the first result in result->string, following the example above this would be a number 4, it stores trash in that position instead. In the second addition, I store a number 2 correctly and that's the final result I get in when I print the result.

Comment: What is `resultado`?

Comment: I'm sorry it's was originally written in spanish and forgot to rename those variables, I'll edit the question

Comment: Are you sure both `num1->string[limit-1]` and `num2->string[limit-1]` are not out-of-range?

Comment: Forget about itoa. If `((int)num1->string[index]) - ((int)'0');` converted from ASCII to integer, then naturally you can do + `'0'` to go the other way around.

Comment: Do your instructions require you to use ```struct BigNumber``` throughout, or would you be allowed to use more efficient processes to perform the sum of 1 to 100, and then just convert it back to a ```BigNumber``` once at the end?  Or would that be cheating in this situation?

Comment: @NateB The only restriction I have is to implement the sum function with the given signature, in this case `BigNumber *sum(BigNumber* num1, BigNumber* num2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the `itoa` function **is** a problem (though, as you have also suggested, maybe not the only one).

The [`itoa` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) converts its first argument into a **null-terminated string** - so, as well as writing the character representation of `digitResult` at the indicated place in the string, it also ***adds a `'\0'` character after it***. Thus, your string will **always** be terminated immediately after the last digit you write, and `12` + `12`, giving `24` will appear to be just the first character: `2`.

What you can do instead is to convert the digit yourself (reversing the operation you used to get the `d1` and `d2` values), then just *directly* set the string element to the converted digit.

So, instead of:

```c
    itoa(digitResult, &result->string[index], 10);
```

use:

```c
    result->string[index] = (char)(digitResult + '0');
```